# Boostrap modal showing a white box surrounding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this dynamically created bootstrap modal

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header bg-primary">
            Foo
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            Bar
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the `.modal-footer` is populated via an object, much like jQuery's dialog

```
function dialog(opt) {
    $modal.create();
    $modal.on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
         $(this).remove();
    });
    $modal.find('.modal-footer').append(
    (function(){
        var res = [], key, val;
        for(key in opt.buttons) {
            value = opt.buttons[key];
            res.push(
                (function(key, value) {
                    return $('<button type="button" data-dismiss="modal">').on('click', function() {
                        value();
                    }
                })(key, value)
            );
        }
        return res;
    })()
    );
    $('body').append($modal);
    $modal.modal();
}
```

so I can call it like this

```
dialog({
    buttons: {
        Ok: function() { doSomething(); }
    }
});
```

The problem is that `.modal.fade` is showing like a white div around the proper modal, blocking the view of all the page.

The reason I showed how I create it is that I have another static modal with custom content in the page that it's showing correctly.

The functionality is the same in both cases, If I click outside the modal it disappear, but it's quite annoying and I don't want to break one make the other work.

I didn't add any custom css to the modal, by I'm requesting the viewport

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1024" />
```

Other thing, I'm using both IE8 and IE11 (and it's the same in both)

Comment: Remove fade class on modal. It should only be class="modal". The class fade is not supported in IE. https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/3672

Comment: it didn't change anywhing. I wish I didn't have to use modal *and* jQuery UI on the same webpage